# ruby on railsで制作したものをnetlifyにpushして見れるようにしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netlify

ruby on railsで制作した写真投稿アプリをポートフォリオ用にnetlifyを使用して見れるようにしたいのです。

ターミナルで

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "pixcelgram"
git push -u origin master
```

とした後にnetlify https://app.netlify.com　にて

New site from git　のボタンを押して

左下のGitHubボタン押すと私のgithubに飛んでpixelgramを選ぶと

https://gyazo.com/87834113636ad8f7c604ef4d62d1050a
となりそのままBasic build settingを空の状態でDeploy advancedにすると

https://gyazo.com/dba57b42dcb345c02c3fc21ac8b7e31a

となってしまいます。

何がダメなのでしょうか？

Basic build settingになにかrailsで設定した物を入れないといけないのでしょうか？
ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

> Netlify is meant for Static Site Generators, that build static websites from a build command.
>
> (和訳) Netlify は静的なサイトジェネレーター、つまりビルド用のコマンドで静的なウェブサイトをビルドするものののために作られています。

https://community.netlify.com/t/ruby-on-rails-app-does-not-work-on-netlify/982/3